# Microsoft Access memo datatype to MySQL Datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, sqldatatypes, memo

What datatype in MySQL would be best to use for data that was in Memo on Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEXT would be a good match.

Text is a blob field that is meant to store strings.
blob is the same for binary data.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Make sure you use a text/blob variant that is large enough to hold the data that is currently in your `memo` field.
When in doubt `longtext` will hold up to 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be the [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) type in MySQL you are looking for.

The equivalent on Microsoft SQL server would now be NVARCHAR(MAX) on newer versions, and NTEXT on older versions.