# Converting MEMO Ms Jet DB Data type to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba, jet

I have a Access 97 VBA program that copies a bunch of information off a PCOM terminal emulator. 
I would like to sync this database with a remote sql server we have.
I was unable to find anyone who did this using MS Access 97, so I decided to do it my way. 
The remote database has been conected with Access 97.
This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
Set qweMensagens = Mdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM AtualizarMensagens WHERE AtualizarMensagens.contrato_bb = '" & contratoVAR & "';")
If qweMensagens.RecordCount > 0 Then GoTo MOVENEXTNOW3
qweMensagens.AddNew
qweMensagens!contrato_bb = qweCont!Contrato
qweMensagens!mensagem = qweCont!mensagem
qweMensagens!Data = data_padrao
qweMensagens!Append = qweCont!Append
qweMensagens!qweContratos = qweCont!qweContratos
qweMensagens!men_data_evento = qweCont!men_data_evento
qweMensagens!men_data_movimento = qweCont!men_data_movimento
qweMensagens.Update
```

Problem happens with this line:
    qweMensagens!mensagem = qweCont!mensagem
Run time error 3163 - data too big for field.

The qweCont!mensagem field on the MS Access DB is a **MEMO** with ~3000 Char. 
And I already tried to change the qweMensagens!mensagem field on the MySQL DB to LONGTEXT and LONGBLOB.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914959/microsoft-access-memo-datatype-to-mysql-datatype) didn't help at all. It still gives the same error.

I realyzed that it could be a text type problem, but the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727583/export-ms-access-memo-field-and-convert-unicode) wasn't helpful at all. And even [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/06/access-to-sql-server-migration-understanding-data-type-conversions.aspx) they said I should use LONGTEXT for MEMO types.

Am I missing something here? Can I force the data conversion of the MEMO type into UTF-8 or ANSI before sending to the mysql server?

EDIT:

Weird, if I copy the MEMO field and paste it on a table using MySql Workbench it works fine... maybe I should set up a variable to copy the information?

EDIT2:

That didn't work. Still says that the field can't handle that much information. I'm starting to think it's something about the way access is handling the sittuation... Maybe there's a way to append this information into MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on **MySQL** but can you not just use the **Left** function to limit the length of characters you're putting into the new column.  Obviously using a number which is the maximum that will fit in the column.

The problem then is if there are any records with a longer value in the **memo** column they would end up being truncated and the data would be lost.

Also you could create more than one column and put the 1st half in one column and the 2nd half in another one.

Hope this helps, thanks Mark

Comment: Actually you just gave a few ideas. Gonna try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try it!

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=<SeuServidor>;Database=<nomeDoBanco>;User=<usuario>;Password=<senha>;Option=3;"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

While Not qweCont.EOF
    ssql = vbNullString
    ssql = ssql & "Insert into AtualizarMensagens Values ([contrato_bb],[Mensagem],[Data],[Append],[qweContratos],[men_data_evento],[men_data_movimento]) Values("
    ssql = ssql & "'" & qweCont!Contrato & "','" & qweCont!Mensagem & "','" & data_padrao & "','" & qweCont!Append & "','" & qweCont!qweContratos & "',"
    ssql = ssql & "'" & qweCont!men_data_evento & "','" & qweCont!men_data_movimento & "'"
    ssql = ssql & " where AtualizarMensagens.contrato_bb = '" & contratoVar & "'"
    cnn.Execute ssql
    qweCont.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Copilling error : Type defined by user was not defined. 
It stops with 'Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection'. I am using access 97.